# Shorter generic signature

Tags: swift, generics

I have a class that uses generic type, which itself has generic type:

```
internal class WorldObjectsDataSource<WorldObjectType, ObjectsProvider: WorldObjectsProvider<WorldObjectType>> {
```

I need to use both `WorldObjectType` and `ObjectsProvider` in this class, but as you can see `WorldObjectType` is tight to type in generic `ObjectsProvider`, and is always the same. When I'm creating instance of this class I need to define `WorldObjectType` twice, like:

```
let ds1 = WorldObjectsDataSource<WorldObjectSUBCLASS, WorldObjectsProvider<WorldObjectSUBCLASS>>()
```

Is there some way, to shorten this to just include `WorldObjectsProvider<WorldObjectSUBCLASS>` and from this definition get `WorldObjectSUBCLASS` in my class? So that I would be able to use:

```
let ds1 = WorldObjectsDataSource<WorldObjectsProvider<WorldObjectSUBCLASS>>()
```

and inside WorldObjectsDataSource know type `WorldObjectSUBCLASS`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeking in your last line of code is not possible, you can't just omit one of the generic parameters if your class has two. However, you can create a typealias for the specific generic type if `WorldObjectSUBCLASS` will always be the same.

```
typealias WorldObjectAlias = WorldObjectsDataSource<WorldObjectSUBCLASS, WorldObjectsProvider<WorldObjectSUBCLASS>>

let ds1 = WorldObjectAlias()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic type alias:

```
typealias WorldDataSource<T> = WorldObjectsDataSource<T, WorldObjectsProvider<T>>
let ds1 = WorldDataSource<WorldObjectSUBCLASS>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this actually is not what I need, as I want to be able to pass various second parameter `WorldObjectsProvider<T>`, and from it infer `T` and not pass it as first parameter. The way you shown doesn't give me any additional information, because I need to always use `WorldObjectsProvider` with generic `T` specified, but what if I want to subclass `WorldObjectsProvider`. For example class P: WorldObjectsProvider<String>. I should be able then to just pass `P` as a parameter and from it get `String` in class.

Comment: Using solution you have shown is not giving me flexibility for WorldObjectsProvider subclass, and actually I could achieve the same just by using only `T` in generics of this class, without `WorldObjectsProvider<T>` - because I could just execute `WorldObjectsProvider<T>()` in class body and have the same result. But this is not enough, I want to pass just generic type of `WorldObjectsProvider<T>`, which can be also subclass of `WorldObjectsProvider` and get `T` from it in class body. I think it's not possible, but wanna make sure.